# NavigationControllerにTabBarControllerを追加する方法について

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

お世話になっております。

現在iOS開発をしているのですが、一部の画面をTab形式で表示したいと思っています。
流れとしては
NavigationController->MainViewController->TabBarController

としたいと思っています。
ですが、調べてみるとNavigationControllerのStackにTabBarControllerを積むと
ViewControllerで追加したNavigation Itemの設定が反映されないとの意見がありました。
NavigationItemは使用したいのですが、この場合、Tabを表現する方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: AppleのUIガイドラインでは、
Don’t use a tab bar to give users controls that act on elements in the current screen or app mode. If you need to provide controls, including a control that displays a modal view, use a toolbar instead (for usage guidelines, see Toolbar). 

 とあるので、あなたのUIデザインでは、レビューを通らない可能性大です。

Comment: さっそくのコメントありがとうございます。
翻訳しながら読んでみたのですが、Toolbarを使って実現しろとの
事でしょうか。。。これも含め少し考がえてみます。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちがいますよ。tabBarを使う場合は、常に、tabBarを表示するようにせよ。例外は、モーダルな表示のみ。画面によって、tabBarの内容を替えるな。ということです。

Comment: 訂正ありがとうございます。
なるほど、Modalを除き、一部のViewControllerだけTabBarを使用するのはダメってことですね。
使用するなら最初からTabBarを表示させなさいって事ですね。
ありがとうございました。
一部のViewControllerだけTabBarを使用する方法があればいいのですが。。。模索してみます。

Answer (score 1):

TabBarControllerを使わずに、MainViewControllerに独自のUIButtonをフッターに複数設置し、subviewを切替えるようなものを作ったら良いと思います。
view要素しては

■ MainViewController.view
├containerView
　├tabPageFirst
　└tabPageSecond
└tabMenuView
　├tabBtnFirst
　└tabBtnSecond

のようなものviewを作り
例えば、tabBtnSecondが押されたアクションで

```
self.containerView.bringSubviewToFront(tabPageSecond)
```

という形で、最前面への切替で同じようなものが作れるのではいかがでしょう。